# Bug in Knockout JS with <select> element inside foreach loop

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout JS to create a simple drop-down `<select>` box.  I started by trying to use the example given in the Knockout JS docs:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries"></select>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var viewModel = {
        availableCountries : ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']) 
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```

This works perfectly.

However, if I place the `<select>` element INSIDE a `foreach` loop:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: [1,2,3]">
    <select data-bind="options: availableCountries"></select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        availableCountries : ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain'])
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

...now, all of a sudden, KnockoutJS is not able to find a reference to `availableCountries`.  Chrome reports the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return [1,2,3] }"
Message: Unable to process binding "options: function (){return availableCountries }"
Message: availableCountries is not defined
```

This really looks like a bug in KnockoutJS...  am I doing something wrong here, or is this simply a bug?

Comment: Did my answer help you with the problem? Is there anything else I can elaborate on?

Answer (score 4):

Once you data-bind using a for-each, you are in the scope (also known as **binding context**) of the element of the for loop and it can't find a reference to availableCountries anymore.

Have you tried

```
$parent.availableCountries
```

If it's not its direct parent, the following might help (depending on your code):

```
$root.availableCountries
```

To learn more about binding context: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: it should be $parent.availableCountries

Comment: +1 depends on where the viewmodel is defined obviously, but in this case it is better to use $parent. Thanks!